# How does Hindu life make different from any other religion?

Tags: culture, india

I had a discussion with my friend that Indian (Hindu) culture is restricted, or one should obey their elders, respect them, and do what elders want not what that individual wants. I was like this is not Indian(Hindu) culture this is pure dogmatic thinking.

I want suggestion/opinion on what a Hindu life mean. My thoughts on this topic is, If you are atheist then you have "karma" to serve, if you theism then you have "dharma" to serve. If you believe in **dharma** then you, if you believe in **karma** then nature is there for you.

I am in search of that what does actually Indian (specifically Hinduism) is.

Comment: Your question may be broad. If you are confused about Dharma and Karma for theist and Atheist, you can ask those questions alone.

Comment: Looking for a summery about my question, why in the name of Indian culture there are so many people behaving dogmatic, whereas they are under impression of their own beliefs.